# Using script engines from IE/Edge for testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, internet-explorer, web-applications

We are developing a web-app and would like to set up unit-testing of a relatively large library of logic and interface code (javascript).

In our test suit we are invoking v8 on our test suit, but have recently had issues where the tests pass on v8, but fail in usage in IE/Edge du to some functions not implemented in that javascript engine.

Thus, we are now trying to see if we can use the Edge (and or IE11) javascript engine from "the command line" in order to run through the test suit.

Does anyone know if this is possible? It is a rather large library so running it through the full browser by e.g. generating test pages in html including all the js code would be less than ideal.